# SQL Server alternative for the following function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, oracle

**Intro**

Consider the following @string ( '4533-32424-324', '212-323213-21223', 'FSE24-2313', '432D232')

In Oracle SQL, we just use `REGEXP_SUBSTR(@STRING, '[^-]+')` to get anything before the first '-' occurrence.

The output I get in Oracle is `4533, 212, FSE24, 432D232` which is correct.

DBFIDDLE for Oracle is here with output desired:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8523581038c3c53deff57f142494d824

**Question**

I am trying to do this in SQL Server, and I get BLANK not a NULL value but BLANK if there is no '-' occurrence.

This is the statement I use in SQL Server:

```
SUBSTRING (@STRING, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @STRING))
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value even when there is no hyphen, add that to the search string:

```
select substring(@STRING, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @STRING + '-') - 1)
```

Oracle treats the empty string and `NULL` as the same thing -- which violates the standard and is different from other databases.  An empty string is appropriate if `@STRING` starts with a hyphen.  If you want to convert this to `NULL`, use `NULLIF()`:

```
select nullif(substring(@STRING, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @STRING + '-') - 1), '')
```

Comment: Hi Gordan, Thanks for the update, but, the result contains a '-' at the end. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: @StackOne . . . Just subtract 1.  I edited the answer.